# If !empty statement not working / event manager plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

This is for event manager on wordpress.

The following echos "**Website:**" even if the field is empty.

```
<?php
if ( !empty( $EM_Event->event_contact['Url'] ) ) {
    echo $EM_Event->output(' ');
} else {
    echo $EM_Event->output('<strong>Website:</strong> #_CONTACTURL{Url} ') ; 
}
?> </p>
```

How can I get it to only echo "**Website:**" if there is a www.website.com entered but not echo "**Website:**" if there is no www.website.com entered?

Comment: Use `var_dump` to find out what that variable _actually_ contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing `echo $EM_Event->output('<strong>Website:</strong> #_CONTACTURL{Url} ') ;` when `$EM_Event->event_contact['Url']` **IS** empty.

Run a var_dump($EM_Event->event_contact['Url']) right before the if, show us what it prints.

Comment: removing the `!` prints nothing, even if `$EM_Event->event_contact['Url']` is not empty

Comment: Whats is the value that `$EM_Event->event_contact['Url']` is bringing?
Here you have a list of what PHP considers empty: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: So if a user has an website url defined on their wordpress profile, `$EM_Event->event_contact['Url']` loops their url to the `EM_Event` page. If they don't have a url defined nothing shows up on the `EM_Event' page. This works great until I try to add the "**Website:**" before it.

Comment: Run a  `var_dump($EM_Event->event_contact['Url'])` right before the `if`, show us what it prints.

Comment: Now I'm thinking this is something weird the plugin that I can't figure out.

Comment: var_dump returns as null.

Comment: Yeah, `empty(null)` returns `true`, so maybe you need to consider a bug or something like this in your plugin. But if the answer helped you, please check is as correct.